# Does Python have anything like Ruby's Fog?

Tags: python, ruby, cloud, fog

Read about Fog: http://fog.io

Does Python have anything like it? (a library for cloud services.)

Does it need one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've only just looked at the Fog website, but it reminds me of [Apache Libcloud](http://libcloud.apache.org/).

Answer (score 5):

Python [boto](http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/index.html) is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: Python Boto is for Amazon only, but the question asks for something like Fog, which is also aimed at other cloud providers.